# Compilation failed, PLS-00103 pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql

```
create or replace TRIGGER  lening_bri
BEFORE
update on lening
for each row
begin

if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
  :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;


if :old.terugbetaald = 'Y' and :new.terugbetaald = 'N' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := NULL;
end if;


if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;

if old.datumterugbetaald IS NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'Y'
end if;

if :old.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald IS NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'N'
end if;

end;
```

Everytime I run it I get this compilation foul

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue. Compilation failed, line 23 (22:40:46) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

Comment: Check the last two ifs. The assignment in there, you're suddenly using `=` instead of `:=`. In the first two you're doing it right. Also, why do  you have all those `begin`s? They are not needed. One `begin .. end` for the trigger body, and the rest is just `if .. end if` blocks. No extra begins or ends needed in this case.

Comment: Thank u but now i got this problem

Comment: Yes, more syntax errors, missing semicolons. I've updated my answer with that now, but I hope you get better at debugging syntax errors soon, because you're gonna have a hard time if you have to ask about every one of them. :-)
For the future, please ask new questions as a new question instead of replacing the contents and code of the original question. Stack Overflow also serves as an archive for questions (so people can search before asking a new question), and if the question is modified, the answers don't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got too many `begin`s. They are not part of the if, but of the trigger body. If you indent the code, you see how it should be. A begin..end for the trigger, and some if..end ifs for the conditionals.

Also, the assignment should use `:=` instead of `=`. You've missed that in last two pairs of ifs, as well as the semicolons to terminate those statements.

```
create or replace trigger lening_bri
before update on lening
for each row
begin

  if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
    :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
  end if;

  if :old.terugbetaald = 'Y' and :new.terugbetaald = 'N' then
    :new.datumterugbetaald := NULL;
  end if;

  if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
    :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
  end if;

  if :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then 
    :new.terugbetaald := 'Y';
  end if;

  if :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then 
    :new.terugbetaald := 'N';
  end if;

end;
```

Btw, I'm a bit confused by your code. It looks like you want to be able to either set the flag terugbetaald (paid back), and fill the date (pay back date) when the flag is set, or you accept the date to be set, and update the flag accordingly. Feels a bit double to me. Why not make the flag a calculated virtual column?

Also, the third if is the same as the first, and the condition on the last if is reversed, should be `:new.datumterugbetaald IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction

Answer (score 0):

you have many syntax errors. check the below solution:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  lening_bri
BEFORE
update on lening
for each row
begin
if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
  :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;

begin
if :old.terugbetaald = 'Y' and :new.terugbetaald = 'N' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := NULL;
end if;

begin
if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;

begin
if :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then 
    :new.terugbetaald := 'Y';
end if;

begin
if :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then 
    :new.terugbetaald := 'N';
end if;

end;
```